# ScrollView in KivyMD does not add widgets one at a time

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

When I add the elements to the list there is a significant delay, because each time they are added in one fell swoop when the for loop finishes. I would like to understand how to make the elements be added one at a time, because the more elements there are, the more waiting for the loop to finish represents a problem. Thanks in advance.

KV:

```
<Users>
...
ScrollView:
    MDList:
        id: scroll
<ListItemWithCheckbox@OneLineAvatarIconListItem>:
    MyAvatar:
        source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-128.png"
    MyCheckbox:
        id: check
```

Python:

```
class Users(MDScreen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids.topappbar.ids.label_title.font_size = "18sp"
        for i in range(300):
            self.ids.scroll.add_widget(Factory.ListItemWithCheckbox(text="[size=15]Item %d[/size]" % i))
```

I tried for days to solve the problem, also using the Clock library, but without obtaining particular results. I think I should act in another way, but I really don't know which way to go anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your loop is running on the main thread, and the GUI cannot be updated until you yield the main thread (which happens when your `on_enter()` method returns.

A fix is to start another thread that controls the adding of new widgets. A complication is that adding new widgets must be done on the main thread, so that new thread must run the `add_widget()` back on the main thread. Here is a modified version of your `Users` class that uses this approach:

```
class Users(MDScreen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids.topappbar.ids.label_title.font_size = "18sp"
        Thread(target=self.do_on_enter, daemon=True).start()

    def do_on_enter(self):
        # this is running on a new thread
        for i in range(300):
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.do_add, i))

    def do_add(self, i, dt):
        # this runs back on the main thread
        self.ids.scroll.add_widget(Factory.ListItemWithCheckbox(text="[size=15]Item %d[/size]" % i))
```

Comment: Thank you, but with your code the problem remains, nothing changes. Do I need to change anything in your code?